# Правильное получение записей из БД

Tags: php, phalcon, mysql

Здравствуйте! Пользуюсь фреймворком phalcon. Но думаю во всех фреймфорках таким же образом всё устроено. В общем есть таблица users, в ней есть поле group_id. Мне нужно из этой таблицы получить: все записи с group=3, 1 запись с type='senior', 1 запись с type='junior'. Так как это фреймворк MVC у меня есть модель Users. И вот так я получаю эти 3 цели:

```
$users = Users::find('group=3');
$senior = Users::findFirst('type="senior" and group=3');
$junior = Users::findFirst('type="junior" and group=3');
```

Я здесь вижу целых 3 запроса в БД. Когда можно обойтись одним, не используя фреймворк. Или используя фреймворк, но сделав поиск в $users. Или же фреймворк на столько умный, что понимает, что запросы одинаковые и ищет уже по ранее найденному, а не в целой БД? Правильно ли я сделал?

Comment: Фреймворк ни до чего не догадывается. Он делает ровно то, что ему сказали. Никто не гарантирует, что за это время не появилось новых записей, как и то, что пользователю фреймворка не требуется именно отследить появление новых записей. Поэтому на эти три команды он выполнит три запроса.

> Когда можно обойтись одним, не используя фреймворк.

Разве данные за один запрос не будут лежать в `$users`?

Comment: а какой такой один запрос, чтобы он три массива сделал, подскажите-ка ? Как сказал @Fike если запросов делать не хочется несколько - используйте фильтр на $users.

Comment: Ну а как сделать поиск по $users? Просто сделать функцию, в которой будет цикл с поиском нужной записи? Или же лучше 3 запроса?

Answer (score 1):

В `phalcon` для усложнённых запросов предусмотрен `Query\Builder`.

Для того чтобы выполнить запрос к конкретной модели (в вашем случае Users) используйте `Users::query()`. Можно отдельно создать класс `Builder` и самому указать с какими моделями и полями вы хотите работать:

```
$qb = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder();

$result = $qb->from('Models\Users')
->andWhere('group >= :group:', ['group' => 3])
->andWhere('type = :typeSenior:', ['typeSenior' => 'senior'])
->andWhere('type = :typeJunior:', ['typeJunior' => 'junior'])
->getQuery()->execute();
```

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html

Comment: Направление мыслей верное, но такой запрос не сработает, так как все через AND, то есть дай пользователей, которые одновременно Senior и Junior, а такие вряд ли будут. Ему нужно UNION делать